# Where to place Rythm template files

Tags: rythm

I am having a weird problem with Rythm templates. Currently, I have these templates placed under

`myPrj/src/main/java/resources/templates` folder.

And all the Java source code is under `myPrj/src/main/java` folder.

When I try to render, sometimes Rythm is generating the XML file and sometimes I get the file name as is.

I have the `home.template` set to "templates" folder:

```
params.put("home.template", "templates");

String myTemplateString = Rythm.render("MyTemplate.xml", parameters);
```

Looks like Rythm is not able to locate `MyTemplate.xml` and resulting in emitting `MyTemplate.xml` as the output.

Can you please help me on how to solve this problem?? In addition, would appreciate if you can guide me on what should be the appropriate location to place these templates.

Answer (score 0):

`home.template` is the configuration key to initialize template engine, not the parameter to render your template.

My implementation of your app looks like

```
public class App {
    private static RythmEngine engine;

    private static void echo(String msg, Object ... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static void init() {
        echo("initializing rythmengine");
        Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        conf.put("home.template", "templates");
        engine = new RythmEngine(conf);
        echo("engine initialized");
    }

    private static void render() {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("foo", "FOO");
        params.put("bar", "BAR");
        String result = engine.render("MyTemplate.xml", params);
        echo(result);
    }

    private static void doJob() {
        echo("start doing real job now...");
        render();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        init();
        doJob();
    }
}
```

The complete sample code could be found at https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/tree/master/samples/demo_fo_SO_150529. Download the sample code and run `mvn compile exec:java` to see the result

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested and I still see the file name as the result from engine.render() method.

Comment: Can you please help me as I am completely stuck with this problem.

Comment: send me your prj pkg and i will have a look

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem lies within the path for the `home.template`. The [example on their website](http://rythmengine.org/doc/tutorial.md#hello) might help.

If I'm not mistaken, you should use `params.put("home.template", "resources/templates");` rather than `params.put("home.template", "templates");`.

Generally speaking, this kind of behaviour takes place any time Rythm can't find the template. I found it is best to check both, the path and file name. If necessary, simply use an absolute path to your template to make sure it points to the right directory. After you got the right path, you might want to change it back to be relative.